# Is there any difference between "talk over" and "talk through"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference between *talk over* and *talk through*? For example:

> I will have to **talk** my initiative **over** with the CEO.
>
> I will have to **talk** my initiative **through** with the CEO.

In my previous question I asked about the difference between *talk about* and *talk over* and was told that *talk over* can mean to talk something thoroughly. Does that mean that *talk over* and *talk through* are complete synonyms?

Comment: No, "talk through" usually means to guide someone step by step through something. The phrase "talk over" usually means a more general discussion.